# hard negative mining equivalent for prediction/forecasting problems

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, robust

**Input:** past history 3D velocity components of an object up to time t; history size is w (window or lag) seconds in the past.
**Output:** predicted future possible velocities for times in the range t < times <= T seconds.

Say I build some temporal neural network to forecast my future velocities at these different times (horizons) and my historical data has some patterns which can be learned for non-zero and non-constant velocities. To improve model performance I can look at input data in the test/validation set where my model failed to yield a good prediction and use ***active learning*** to enrich my training set with similar examples.

I want to draw an analogy to ***hard negative mining***, where input data might not be realistic but might help me improve model ***robustness*** in addition to using active learning, e.g. in image classification problems for k classes, I can introduce k+1 class where I proceed to feed in random images into my network (even just noise) and get the network to classify images as the negative k+1 class.

The two non-likely historical data cases that I can think of are:

1. object is perfectly stationary (zero velocity). What do I expect the neural network to learn from this data? Given most arhitectures, I would mostly likely be training the bias terms to not overfit and output something close to zero as the forecast.
2. acceleration is zero (constant velocity): this is a bit tricky, since my last observed velocity is a perfect predictor for future velocities, i.e. if I train on this data (which in likelihood has some noise), my model will be massively overfitting (just learns noise in the training set), as the underlying motion model is trivial (just output last observed velocity for all prediction horizons).

Is there a problem with case #2 above? How else can one improve model robustness for this forecasting problem?

Also consider the fact that earlier prediction horizons for time t+dt have again last observed velocity as the near-perfect predictor, which is not the case for longer horizon T-dt (in other words, longer horizons require more complex models, but I'm fitting a single model of fixed complexity to this data).